# Pyquery get element count

Tags: python, pyquery

In the python library [`pyquery`](https://github.com/dsc/pyquery), the query result is a `<class 'pyquery.pyquery.PyQuery'>` object, not a dictionary or an array. So how to get the query result **count** of `result` in this example?

```py
dom = '<p><span><em>Whoah!</em></span></p><p><em> there</em></p>'
pq = PyQuery(m)
result = pq('p').find('em')     #p = "[<em>, <em>]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, you can use the `size()` function of the resulting `<class 'pyquery.pyquery.PyQuery'>` object, like this.

```
dom = '<p><span><em>Whoah!</em></span></p><p><em> there</em></p>'
pq = PyQuery(m)
result = pq('p').find('em')
print( result.size() ) #output: 2
```

#### Edit:

As @MatiasCicero pointed out in comments, using `len` on the `<class 'pyquery.pyquery.PyQuery'>` object is a more pythonic way. Example:

```
print( len(result) ) #output: 2
```

Comment: By they way, you can also use `len(result)` which looks more pythonic to me